# Push Notifications setup using iOS Enterprise and Developer accounts

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, enterprise, iphone-developer-program

I have a developer account which I use for developing iOS applications, as well as uploading to the AppStore. My app has push notifications enabled.

Now, I want to be able to test it by distributing it to more users. So I though of using an iOS Enterprise account for this.  Besides the functionality, I would also want to test push notifications. But, since an App ID is unique, I can't create a provisioning profile in the iOS Enterprise account using the same App ID of the app in the iOS Developer account.

I can only think of changing the bundle ID, and generating new provisioning profiles for the new bundle ID as the solution. But I have services in the app which use the bundle ID too, so changing them will affect those services.

Are there any other ways to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) than an iOS Enterprise Developer account. With an Enterprise account, you cannot use the same bundle ID (at least not for push notifications - for other services, you might get away with using a wildcard bundle ID). The old fashioned way - using AdHoc distribution profiles, works as well but then you need to manually add each device ID (which is probably why you're using the Enterprise program now).

(Also, note that an Enterprise account may (officially) only be used for installing apps with employees of said enterprise.)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

:: Create the PEM file for distribution cert and Host it on you server.
:: Create the App Build with adHoc profile and distribute it to the devices which are added to that particular adHoc profile.[You can add specific devices to adHoc build]
:: Now you can test your push notifications as the PEM file create is for distribution cert and same will be used for AppStore distribution.